# django - restricting user access to related models

Tags: django, permissions

In my project, I have a `Bot` model that has a Foreign key to a `User` model. Each user should manage his own `Bot` instances, so in my `BotListView`, `BotUpdateView`, `BotCreateView` etc. I check if the user owns the object/object list, which is fairly trivial.

However, `Bot` has a lot of dependent models: `ContentBlock`s, `Campaign`s, `Subscriber`s, `Question`s etc., all of which have FKs to `Bot`. These dependent models in turn have their own dependent models, e.g. `Campaign` has `CampaignDelivery`s, `Subscriber` has `Ticket`s etc. And for all of those I need access control.

So in all my views I have to go three or four FK's up the relations to find the particular `Bot` to check the object user. It looks like so:

```
if delivery.campaign.bot.user == request.user
if answer.question.bot.user == request.user
if renewal.ticket.subscriber.bot.user == request user
...
```

you get the idea. I need a simpler way than this.

I thought of assigning an FK to `User` to each and every one of my model to simplify the owner lookup, but this will be even less manageable than now. Also, storing FKs to `User` in millions of `CampaignDelivery` rows is a huge overhead.

There's also a way to define an `owner()` method on every model and have my views check `object.owner()` against `request.user`. This is my current solution but it looks rather clumsy.

I believe this is a common situation in big Django projects, so what is the best practice for access control like this?

Comment: Did you make serializer for each model?

Comment: @FadyAlfred I don't have API in my project, so I do not understand why you are asking about serializers. Please clarify.